# Duplicate admin menu posts page

Tags: wordpress, product, blogs, posts

I have a Wordpress site that I used the 'Posts' menu to create product pages as the site works as a catalog with no online purchasing. I am now trying to set up a blog in the same install. Is it possible to duplicate the 'Posts' menu option and page functions to create a new admin menu for 'Blog'. My goal is so that the blog and products function separately so you won't have access to a product post when in the blog section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new post type.

Please check this plugin this helps you a lot. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dipak Dholakiya. The plugin worked great, though I decided to do it without plugins. I found a solution posted from 'wpEASYtuts'. I set up a new Custom Post Type and am using it for the Products. This is inside my functions.php file

```
function product_post() {
$labels = array(
  'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
  'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
  'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'product' ),
  'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product' ),
  'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
  'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
  'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
  'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
  'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
  'not_found'          => __( 'No product found' ),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No product found in the Trash' ), 
  'parent_item_colon'  => '',
  'menu_name'          => 'Products',
);
$args = array(
  'labels'        => $labels,
  'description'   => 'Holds product and product specific data',
  'public'        => true,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
  'has_archive'   => true,
  'taxonomies'  => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
);
register_post_type( 'products', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_post' );
```

And then proceeded to use the 'single.php' file renamed to 'single-products.php'.

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.